# OWL Carousel image not right size at first

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, carousel, owl-carousel

I am using OWL Carousel and I have coded it so there will be one image displayed and then every 15 seconds the next image will slide in. I have set the width to be 100% of the screen so and coded the js appropriately so in theory there should be ONE image at a time at full size....however what happens is it shows all the images rather small and then if i resize the screen even 1 pixel it snaps into how it should be.....

any idea on how to avoid having to resize the screen to get the image to be full sized ?

Here is my HTML

```
<div class="owl-carousel">
    <img src="assets/background1.jpg" />
    <img src="assets/background2.jpg" />
    <img src="assets/background3.jpg" />
</div>
```

Here is my js

```
var owl = $('.owl-carousel');
owl.owlCarousel({
    singleItem: true,
    items:1,
    loop:true,
    margin:10,
    autoplay:true,
    autoplayTimeout:15000,
    autoplayHoverPause:true


});
$('.play').on('click',function(){
    owl.trigger('autoplay.play.owl',[1000])
})
$('.stop').on('click',function(){
owl.trigger('autoplay.stop.owl')
})
```

Comment: Please be sure to read the descriptions of the tags you put on your questions. This is not a question about the Web Ontology Language ([tag:owl]), but about the OWL Carousel ([tag:owl-carousel]).

Comment: Also, it would probably help if you show some code. Otherwise, how can people identify what you could change in it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Reason could be one of the following:

1. Either you're calling the owl.owlCarousel method before the DOM is loaded. So try initiating it in document ready.
2. Or your .owl-carousel div might be inside a container that is not visible when the DOM is loaded.

I faced a similar issue for using owl carousel in a bootstrap modal and it was fixed by initiating owlCarousel in the `shown` event of bootstrap modal.

Let me know if you need more details on this or you got it fixed.

Comment: Thank you, I was calling the carousel before the DOM was loaded. It works great now!

Comment: @Nitish please check out this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52073169/having-trouble-with-owl-carousel-width-in-initial-load?noredirect=1#comment91097173_52073169