# Owl Carousel width issues when first load

Tags: jquery, css, carousel, owl-carousel

i'm using owl carousel. this is my script:

```
$("#owl-demo").owlCarousel({ 
  items : 3
});
```

i want the container show 3 images. But, here is the picture when first load

[image: First load, before browser get resize]

but when i resize the browser, although just a little bit, size of images change to actual size and setting that i want

[image: Browser got resize]

So, the problem is images preview when i load browser for the first time.
Why this is happening? i think the issues about size of my browser

Comment: I had the same issue time ago, and was because I changed CSS in the items, especially positions and display. Try changing to defaults.

Comment: i didn't change anything. i got from this link http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/demos/itemsCustom.html

Comment: [FIXED] my items in div which it didn't active (im using tab panel). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27006239/owl-carousel-image-not-right-size-at-first?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this problem when I measured the width of the owl-stage container in a working state. And then set the values in the styles like:

```
#photo-gallery .owl-stage {
  min-width: 10317px;
}
```

My JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
        center: true,
        loop:true,
        margin:20,
        autoWidth: true,
        responsive:{
            0:{
                items: 1,
                autoWidth: false
            },
            908:{
                items: 1,
                autoWidth: true
            },
            1236:{
                items: 3
            }
        }
      });
    });
```